# GT70 2PE Dominator Pro (or equal) keyboard backlight

Tags: keyboard, laptop, backlight, msi

Just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop and have been searching the internet for a couple of hours, trying to get my keyboard's backlight to work . I know it works out of the box when you hit the little icon on the laptop, but the only color it's able to show is bright white and I want it to show multiple colors just like on windows.

I have made a little guide for myself for future reference and I felt like posting it here to help other people with the same laptop/keyboard.

Have fun,

Sapphire ~

Answer (score 3):

### Installing the requirements

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
```

### Installing the MSI KLM Alternative

1. Make a folder called `.msi-klm` (or similar)
2. Now create two files inside the folder: `package.json` and `server.js`
3. Open `package.json` and add the following text:

   ```
   { "name": "led-manager", "dependencies": { "msi-keyboard":"*" }}
   ```
4. Save the file
5. Open a terminal and navigate to the folder
6. Run the following command: `npm install`
7. Open `server.js` and add the following text:

   ```
   var keyboard = require('msi-keyboard');

   keyboard.color('left', {color: 'red', intensity: 'high'});  
   keyboard.color('middle', {color: 'green', intensity: 'high'});  
   keyboard.color('right', {color: 'purple', intensity: 'high'});
   ```

### Running the MSI KLM Alternative

Run the following command:

```
cd ~/.msi-klm; sudo node server.js
```

---

### Sources

[MSI Keyboard Project](https://github.com/wearefractal/msi-keyboard)
[Forum Thread](http://forum.techinferno.com/msi/5269-msi-led-controller-linux-windows-mac-%7C-msi-klm-alternative.html)

Comment: In modern `nodejs` packages `npm` installing authomatically, so `sudo apt-get install -y npm` must be avoided. I tried to install `npm` after `nodejs` and got [some errors](http://pastebin.com/fRM7c26b) because really, `npm` already has been installed. I edited the answer.